# Libgdx desktop build doesn't compile

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I configured a desktop application in android studio with libgdx 
which doesn't compile. I also tested it on another pc and there it ran. When I start it I get the following error code:

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'game'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :

Comment: Please narrow down the problem and provide the minimum steps required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show your build.gradle file please.

Answer (score 1):

Google have new maven repo, so it could be the reason.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        google()     // <-- add this 
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Also add in allprojects

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```